# Como cargar fotos de un jframe a otro?

Tags: java, jframe

Buenas estoy haciendo un proyecto para la U! sobre una cartera de cine y tengo dos clases de una admin y otra de cartera! en la clase admin ya tengo listo en un JFrame  para poder subir fotos desde la compu pero ahora ocupo poder que salgan en en clase cartera en un JLabel cuando se sube la imagen! si alguien me puede ayudar aqui dejo el codigo que hise para poder subir las fotos en JFrame de la clase admin!! Muchas gracias

```
private void foto1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    JFileChooser dlg = new JFileChooser();
    dlg.setFileFilter(filter1);

    int option = dlg.showOpenDialog(this);
    if(option==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        String fil = dlg.getSelectedFile().getPath();
        poster1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(fil));

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(fil);

        Image img = icon.getImage();

        Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(400, 240, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg);

        poster1.setIcon(newIcon);
        poster1.setSize(400,300 );

        RutaImagen="";
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías insertar el código con lo que has intentado?

Comment: Osea el codigo que esta ahi ! es para poder subir las imagenes pero en jframe que esta en admin!